# MySQL order by rand but result must exist different specific value

Tags: mysql, random

I'm trying the get random values from SQL but I want results must have minimum one specific value from one column, how can I do it?

For example;

TABLE;

```
id  |  category  |  name
----------------------------
1   |      1     |  A
2   |      2     |  B
3   |      3     |  C
4   |      1     |  D
5   |      3     |  E
6   |      3     |  F
7   |      2     |  G
8   |      3     |  H
```

When I query random four data with category id, results not have all different categories, sometimes result coming like this;

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE category IN (1,2,3) ORDER BY RAND LIMIT 4

id  |  category  |  name
----------------------------
1   |      1     |  A
4   |      1     |  D
3   |      3     |  C
8   |      3     |  H
```

Category 2 is missing in this example but I want every category must in results like that;

```
id  |  category  |  name
----------------------------
3   |      3     |  C <-- One from category 3
4   |      1     |  D <-- One from category 1
7   |      2     |  G <-- One from category 2
5   |      3     |  E <-- All categories ok, it can be random from any of them
```

Sorry for my english, I hope I could explain what I wanted. Results must have minimum one row from where clause "category IN (X,Y,Z)".

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
WITH 
cte AS ( SELECT id, category, name,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY RAND()) rn
         FROM test )
SELECT id, category, name
FROM cte
ORDER BY rn > 1, RAND()
LIMIT ? ;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1752e43bbaafc00e0be730c03654a7f1)

For MySQL version below 8 calculate `rn` in subquery using user-defined variables.

Comment: Thank you, it working nice.